# CSS selector organization

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some working CSS code, but I feel like there should be a more efficient way to organize my desired CSS. Basically, I want two separate CSS areas to behave the same in this instance, but different in others (which are not important to this question).

Here is the working CSS:

```
#paragraph p a:visited, #paragraph2 p a:visited{color:#00f;}  
#paragraph p a:link, #paragraph2 p a:link{color:#f00;}
```

I was envisioning something like this:

```
(#paragraph | #paragraph2) p a{
visited{color:#00f;}
link{color:#f00;}
}
```

I will try to encapsulate my pseudocode in words, in case what I wrote doesn't make sense:

Either #paragraph or #paragraph2, containing a "p" containing an "a". Then, change both the "link" and "visited" attributes w/in the "a" tag.

First off, thanks to anybody who takes the time to read/answer.

Secondly, there may be a better way to organize my document altogether, and it's totally cool if you have suggestions in that area, but I am also genuinely curious if the approach I came up w/ is possible, and how I would accomplish it this way.

Thanks!

Comment: There are many different possible solutions to your question, but none of them are objectively better or worse. You could apply a common class to the two paragraphs, or use a CSS extension such as LESS or Sass, or restructure your document, or just live with what you've got, or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the two paragraphs a class and then select based on the class so that you don't have to repeat yourself. Also, look into [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) if you want better alternatives to regular CSS in this regard.

For example, in Sass you can do this (if you add a .paragraph class to both paragraphs):

```
.paragraph p a {
    visited { color: #00f; }
    link { color: #f00; }
}
```